# Dispatch Bloc Event outside Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm new on Flutter, and I'm trying to create my first app.
In my app I created a singleton class for Network call.

```
class NetworkUtil {
  Config configuration;
  Dio dio;
  static NetworkUtil _instance = new NetworkUtil._internal();
  NetworkUtil._internal();
  factory NetworkUtil(Config config){
    _instance.configuration = config;
    _instance.dio = new Dio();
    return _instance;
  }

  final JsonDecoder _decoder = new JsonDecoder();

  Future<dynamic> post(String url, {Map headers, body, encoding}) {
    url = _instance.configuration.url+url;

    return dio.post(url, data: body).then((response) {
      final String res = response.data;
      return res;
    }).catchError((e){
      if(e.response.data.containsKey("message")){
        //I Need to dispatch event in blocClass
         final _classBloc = BlocProvider.of<classBloc>(context); //I haven't context here 
         _classBloc .dispatch(ErrorMessage(message: e.response.data["message"]));

      }else{
        throw new Exception("System Error");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My problem is that I haven't context so I cant dispatch event in Bloc.

I've been thinking pass context as arguments, but I don't know if it is a Bad Practice, on Android framework is terrible bad Practice pass Context as Arguments and I don't know in Flutter.

Is it possible use BlocProvider outisde widget?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at it wrong. You want to be making a network call as a response to a `bloc` event, so in your processing function - I assume it's gonna be in `mapEventToState` since you're using `flutter_bloc` - you want to have something like:

```dart
// event case
yield LoadingEvent();
try {
  var post = await NetworkUtil.post(...);
  yield CompleteState(post);
} catch (error) {
  // handle errors
  yield ErrorState(error.message);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in this way, if I have 100 network call in my app, I need to write in all the yeld. And then, if I have a repositoryPattern and so the nework call are done inside class repository?